# The mongoose findOneAndUpdate function doesn't seem to be working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a reservation system of sorts using mongoose and nodejs. There are a list of hotels which have number of available rooms as a field. While creating a new booking for a customer, I want to check if the number of available rooms in the particular hotel greater than 0 and if it is, update the number of available rooms in the hotel by reducing it by 1.

Here is my code

-Hotel Model file

```
var hotel: new mongoose.Schema{
name: String, 
availableRooms: {type: Number, default: 1}}
```

-Booking Model file

```
var booking: new mongoose.Schema{
userName: String,
hotelId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'hotel'}
}
```

Here's the code I'm having trouble with.

```
Hotel.findOneAndUpdate({
     _id: hotelId, availableRooms: {$gt: 0}
},{
     $inc : { availableRooms : -1 }
}, function(err){
if (err) throw err
else
{
    booking.create(req.body, function(err, confirmedBooking){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(confirmedBooking)
    });
}
});
```

When I try to create a new booking using postman, it creates the new booking but it doesn't check the available rooms option. If a hotel has zero available rooms, it still goes on to create the booking. Also, the number of available rooms doesn't go below 0 at all.

Comment: I guess you are creating the booking in callback block assuming that it will be called only when the update will happen. I guess even if there are no updates, the callback is being called and your booking object is getting created. you can try to return a writeresult object with err and create the booking if that writeresult really modified any document. As for why your hotel document is not getting updated, I would suggest to call findOne with the query and see if there is really a matching document or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through your code, the `else` clause in the **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** callback is always executed because your code doesn't produce any error, it just isn't checking if there is a matching document from the update query.

You need to check is there is a matching document as well as if the original document has available rooms for you to create the new booking.

The following code implements the specification:

> I want to check if the number of available rooms in the particular hotel greater than 0

```
{ '_id': hotelId, 'availableRooms': { '$gt': 0 } },
```

and if it is,

> update the number of available rooms in the hotel by reducing it by 1.

```
{ '$inc': { 'availableRooms': -1 } },
```

> create a new booking

```
if (hotel && hotel.availableRooms > 0) { /* create booking */ }
```

**Correct update**

```
Hotel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { '_id': hotelId, 'availableRooms': { '$gt': 0 } },
    { '$inc': { 'availableRooms': -1 } }, 
    function (err, hotel) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else if (hotel && hotel.availableRooms > 0) {
            booking.create(req.body, function(err, confirmedBooking){
                if (err) throw err;
                res.json(confirmedBooking);
            });
        }
    }
);
```