# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate updates non-existent entry

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm currently working on adding a "forgot-password"-functionality and am facing a problem which I did not manage to solve on my own.

In my mongoose findOneAndUpdate-function, I noticed that it updates an entry even though said entry doesn't exist.

Here's my function :

```
router.put('/resetpass', (req, res) => {
    const {resetPassLink, password} = req.body;
    Users.findOneAndUpdate({resetPassLink : resetPassLink}, {$set : {password : password, resetPassLink: ''}}, function(error, feedback) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send(feedback);
})
```

})

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895103/the-mongoose-findoneandupdate-function-doesnt-seem-to-be-working) suggested that the user who asked the question, encountered the problem because his function did not produce any errors, however, mine does produce an error.

I'm not sure about what's going wrong in my code. Shouldn't it throw the error once it notices that there's no resetPassLink-field with the value it is looking for?

What exactly am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: what is the behaviour you are expecting to have?

Comment: To get an error message. I actually just found the solution and will delete this question since I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551313/mongodb-node-findone-how-to-handle-no-results and since, after reading that question, I found them to be too similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to improve your query little bit like below :

```
router.put('/resetpass', (req, res) => {
const {resetPassLink, password} = req.body;

Users.findOneAndUpdate({resetPassLink : resetPassLink, resetPassLink: 
{$exists: true}, password: {$exists: true}}, {$set : 
{password : password, resetPassLink: ''}}, (error, feedback) => {
    if (error) {   
    console.log(error)     
   }; else {
    return res.send(feedback);
}
});
```

Comment: How does your answer make any difference really?

Comment: I think he just checks if the values exist so if they don't it would generate an error message

Comment: If particular field is not present in db it gives you error otherwise it can update your data as required.